# Which non-shared Smart Pointer for class member variables

Tags: c++, pointers, shared-ptr, smart-pointers, scoped-ptr

When I have a class that contains pointers as member variables what type of smart pointer should they have if I want don't want to use plain pointers? They do not need to be shared (so no shared_ptr necessary). scoped_ptr won't work since I often need to build the objects outside of the initialization list.

Or is it maybe common practice to use a scoped_ptr during the creation when something can still fail (exceptions thrown etc.) and afterwards assign them to plain pointers?

Comment: Can you give a more concrete example?

Comment: Simple Composition: Object A contains Object B. Object A creates and destroys B. No other object can influence B's lifetime.

Comment: @Benjamin: Why not just make `ObjectB` a non-pointer member?

Comment: @GMan: Because I need to create it dynamically.

Comment: @Benjamin: Ok, *why*? You're not really making any concrete. Ask the problem, not the step.

Comment: @GMan: Constructor arguments for Object B are evaluated during runtime. E.g. parsing a configuration file and use data from that as an argument in the constructor.

Comment: @jalf: Then I have the same problem for the class containing the containing class don't I? ;-)

Comment: `boost::optional` may be more appropriate then. It sounds like what you need is not "a pointer to a dynamically allocated object" specifically, but a way to specify that an object may or may not have been created yet.

Comment: @Benjamin (sorry, I deleted that comment before your reply, I figured it was irrelevant): I don't see why though. Your entire application doesn't have to be inside a single global master class. You're allowed to have more than one class. ;)

Comment: @Bejamin: Honestly it just sounds like a pointer here is a patch for a broken design. Maybe if you re-factored, and/or showed us your real code, it could be fixed.

Comment: I really don't get it, sorry. Everything I create on the stack has to be fully determined while compiling right? How would I be able to create objects on the stack that depend on things that happen during runtime like parsing a config file or user input? I want to do this stuff in constructor and not write init() methods or something like that.

Comment: @Benjamin: Again, give us some concrete stuff. What is "everything" that needs to be fully determined? You can parse a file, and pass something into the constructor.

Comment: Nope everything fine. It was indeed a flaw in my design. Thanks very much for leading me to the right path :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're just wanting to store member pointers in a smart pointer type class so you can't/won't forget to delete them, then a standard choice would be `auto_ptr`.  It's in the STL and is easily "reset" with the `reset()` function when you need to release the current memory allocated to it and replace it with a new object.

You will still want to implement your own copy constructor and assignment operators for the classes which have auto_ptr members.  This is due to the fact that auto_ptrs assignment operator transfers ownership of the underlying object so a default assignment operator will not have the effect you want.

Here is what the class might look like:

```
class X
{
public:
    X() :p(new ClassToManage) {}
    X(const X &copy)
        :p(new ClassToManage(*copy.p))
    {
    }

    X &operator=(const X &rhs)
    { 
        this->p.reset(new ClassToManage(*rhs.p));   
    }   

private:
    std::auto_ptr<ClassToManage> p;
};
```

For all other cases I would suggest `boost::shared_ptr`.  Shared_ptr does do reference counting but you can store them in standard containers which makes them quite useful.

You should ultimately try to rid yourself of using plain pointers for anything which points at allocated memory it's responsible for deleting.  If you want to use a plain pointer for accessing or iterating over a plain ole array etc., then that's fine (but ask yourself why you're not using a std::vector), but when you use them to point at something that it is responsible for freeing then you're asking for trouble.  My goal when writing code is to have no explicit deletes.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `std::auto_ptr`, which was available prior to TR1 and therefore your code is not dependant on a compiler supporting TR1-smartpointers.

Answer (score 0):

Normally I use a deep_copy_ptr. Right now I know of loki smart_ptr and axter smart pointer that do this. It allow the pointer class to be automatically copied somewhat like if it was a normal member variable (you don't need to define a special assignment operator/copy constructor).

I think you don't have to specifically initialize it in the initializer list (but like a normal pointer, don't use it if it do not have a valid value, obviously).